# Dropdown menu View in Flutter

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu, flutter-layout

I have a dropdown in my app like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9v7p.png).

at beginning i am showing "Choose Filters" as the dropdown hint, once any of the item in dropdown in selected and there is a button as `+ icon` once pressed I am doing further operations.

If an option is selected in dropdown its visible in the app, what I want to do is after selecting an option if clicks on that + icon I want instead of that selected dropdown value display the hint i.e "Choose Filters" . Is there any way to that please let me know.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the `DropdownButton` to show the hint again, you need to set it's selected value to `null`. So the variable you are setting on the property `value` of the `DropdownButton` should be set to `null`.

Comment: oh It worked.  didn't thought it was this much simpler, Thank you. you are the one who is clearing all the doubts and gave exact solution what I searching for. Thanks alot!